# JPype error: import jpype ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jpype'

Tags: python-3.x, jpype

I installed JPype in a correct way and anything is fine and my instalation was succeed but when i run my refactor.py from command prompt i have error that i pointed in title.
i hope you can help me for solving this problem.
also i have to point that i am beginner in python3.

here is my code:

```
  import urllib.request
        import os
        import tempfile
        import sys
        import fileinput
        import logging
        import jpype


   logging.basicConfig(filename="ERROR.txt", level= logging.ERROR)
try:
    logging.debug('we are in the main try loop')
    jpype.startJVM("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/ClassWithTest.java", "-ea")
    test_class = jpype.JClass("ClassWithTest")
    a = testAll()
    file_java_class = open("OUTPUT.txt", "w")
    file_java_class.write(a)
except Exception as e1:
        logging.error(str(e1))
        jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Comment: How did you install it? Did you maybe accidentally install in a different environment, e.g. for Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

`startJVM()` function takes the path to the JVM which is like this - `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-10.0.2\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll`. You could use the `getDefaultJVMPath()` function to get the JVM path on your PC. So you can just start the JVM this way:

```
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea")
```

Hope that helps!